# Using tabler angular: Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Tags: angular

I am trying to use [Angular Tabler](https://github.com/tabler/tabler-angular)

```
@tabler/angular-core
@tabler/angular-ui
@tabler/angular-styles
@tabler/angular-forms
```

After npm installing all of these packages and running `ng serve` I get the error:

```
Argument of type '{ read: typeof ViewContainerRef; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; static: boolean; }'.
  Property 'static' is missing in type '{ read: typeof ViewContainerRef; }' but required in type '{ read?: any; static: boolean; }'.ts(2345)
```

This is fixable by changing an object in `horizontal.component.ts`

> @ViewChild('fieldComponent', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false })

However, now on `ng serve` I run into the following issue:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@tabler/angular-core/index.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /Users/me/git//ngapp/node_modules/@tabler/angular-core/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Users/me/git/ngapp/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:838:23)
    at /Users/me/git//ngapp/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but you might be trying to get Angular 8 to compile an Angular 6-7 package. @tabler/angular was last updated on April 26th, before Angular's last release on May 29th.

Since Angular 8, the definition for the ViewContainerRef interface has changed and now the `static: boolean` property is a required of said interface.

Try downgrading your Angular version to 7, it should fix the problem.

Comment: I'd rather not downgrade, this project needs features from angular 8

Comment: Then I guess your need to either submit an issue at the `@tabler/angular` repo or clone the repo yourself, build it with the Angular 8 CLI as in `ng build my-lib` and manually copy your customized library to the node_modules folder of the project.